# MySQL column count from a join

Tags: mysql, join

Is there any way to count all the columns from a `join` result in MySQL?
I've seen that there is a way to do it on a `select` from single tables, but I didn't figure out on how to do it using join.

Comment: _"... count all the columns ..."_ Do you want the count of the number of columns or the number of rows?

Comment: There's no way to count columns.  Counting rows, you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pro tip:** Avoid `SELECT *` unless you have some very good reason to use it. For one thing, it returns redundant columns on `JOIN` queries (in your case the `id` columns from both tables).  Instead, list the names of the columns you want in your `SELECT` clause.

For another thing, it often returns more data than you need in your application. That ties up your network and maybe RAM on your dbms client.

For a third thing, in complex queries like JOINs, the dbms sometimes has to work harder to retrieve all the columns efficiently. This has to do with stuff like *covering indexes*, about which you can read.

**To answer your question**:

You can use the `information_schema` to obtain information about columns in tables. The `COLUMNS` table describes all the tables in your system. Here we count the columns in tables `t1` and `t2`. That's the number of columns you'll get if you `SELECT *` from a join of those tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), table_name
   FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
  WHERE table_name IN ('t1', 't2')
    AND table_schema=DATABASE()
  GROUP BY table_name WITH ROLLUP
```

If you want only the count of columns with different names, you can do this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name), table_name
   FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
  WHERE table_name IN ('t1', 't2')
    AND table_schema=DATABASE()
  GROUP BY table_name WITH ROLLUP
```

But that relies on your database design avoiding using the same name for columns with different meanings. Many database designs aren't like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the mysql cli, but it's a bit of a hack (to put it mildly), might not suit your requirement, and I really can't think how you'd want to use it.

You could try using the PAGER command and count the number of lines returned by running the query with LIMIT 1

e.g. The following JOIN returns 7 columns

```
mysql> SELECT * from tuser1 t1 JOIN tuser2 t2 USING(id) limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
   id: 15
email: hello
  uid: 2
 enum: 3
email: hello
  uid: 2
 enum: 3
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Setting the PAGER to count the output lines, returns 7

```
mysql> PAGER grep -v '\*\*' | wc -l;
PAGER set to 'grep -v '\*\*' | wc -l'
mysql> SELECT * from tuser1 t1 JOIN tuser2 t2 USING(id) limit 1\G
7
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> nopager
PAGER set to stdout
```